# How to restrict user not to enter more than 2 digits before Decimal

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Am using RadNumericTextBox to get Time Duration From user, i want to get only two digits before decimal.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtTrDuration" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" >
                                <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="2"   />
                            </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

`<NumberFormat DecimalDigits="2"   />` this restricts two digits after decimal

is there any other way to achieve this by `javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to limit digits before decimal point. You asign to control an js event (onchange) and execute function to validate control.

You can use this Regex:

**^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}$**

return false if not match!